# Kubernetes: add metadata to manifest based on rules/labels

Tags: kubernetes, manifest, rules

Is there a way to add pod metadata or modify K8S manifest after submission, but before pod gets scheduled? Or is manifest completely immutable?

Situation:
I have an application where I don't have any control over manifest sent to API server, but I would like to modify metadata before pod gets scheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An admission controller seems like a suitable solution to your requirement : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook-alpha-in-18-beta-in-19